# How to code parallel -> sequencial program in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, asynchronous

I want to develop the following program in AS3

```
main -> Async call A -----> join 
     |- Async call B ->|
     |- Async call C ->|
```

-

```
var xmlLoaderA:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlLoaderB:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlLoaderC:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoaderA.load(new URLRequest("http://example.com/a.xml"));
xmlLoaderB.load(new URLRequest("http://example.com/b.xml"));
xmlLoaderC.load(new URLRequest("http://example.com/c.xml"));

xmlLoaderA.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoadedA);
xmlLoaderB.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoadedB);
xmlLoaderC.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoadedC);
```

A Async call has HTTP access and join method merge the data from each HTTP access.
If you have a some example I'm happy.

Comment: parallel and sequential are antonyms. Do you want them requested in order (asynchronously) or do you want them all requested at the same time and be notified once all have completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [raix framework](https://github.com/richardszalay/raix) allows composition of asynchronous operations:

**Edit:** I misunderstood your async requirements. Updated to fetch all three at the same time:

```
Observable.forkJoin([
    Observable.urlRequest(new URLRequest("http://tempuri.org/1"))
    Observable.urlRequest(new URLRequest("http://tempuri.org/2"))
    Observable.urlRequest(new URLRequest("http://tempuri.org/3"))
])
.subscribe(function(values:Array) : void
{
    // values contains result from requests in the original order
});
```

*Disclaimer: I am the author of raix*

Comment: awesome! can I build with FlashDevelop?

Comment: @freddiefujiwara - It's just actionscript, so I don't see why not.